# Authentication login with legacy database in Django

Tags: python, django, custom-backend

I am creating a project in Django and I have a `HelpDesk` database that I would like to use in the project. In the database I have the table `log_user` where the logins information is stored, but I can not find a way to authenticate other than the Django default table.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import Person
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Person(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated sucessfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disable account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Login')
    else:
        form = Person()
        return render(request, 'login2.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Loginteste

class Person(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Loginteste
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Loginteste(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'loginteste'
```

**auth_backend.py**

```
from .models import Loginteste

class MyBackend:
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        user = Loginteste.object.get(username=username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return (request, user)
```

I tried with the default table "User" and the login function worked, but I can not do it with an already existing table (`log_user` in database `HelpDesk`).

Comment: Have you read the docs about [other authentication sources](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#other-authentication-sources) ?

Comment: And if you have not added your second database (HelpDesk) to your project, you can look into [this doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/).

Comment: Yes Ralf, I read this document on custom backend, but I can not develop the logic because I know little about the tool, I've seen several tutorials and other things, but none are really focused on my problem, and everyone uses the "User".

Comment: ok, then, can you be more specific about what is not working? Are you getting an error? And add the code part that is causing you problems.

Comment: It's not a mistake, it's probably a lack of experience. I'll edit my question with the codes.

Comment: form, view and model look ok. Do you have a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)? You will need to write one and add it to `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

Comment: Could you help me with the custom backend? I've been trying to do the custom backend for 3 days and I can not do it.
I've read a lot of documents about the custom backend and watched videos, but I could not put them to practice, I'm going crazy.

Comment: Well, show the backend you got so far and what errors you are having with it.

Comment: Ralf, I added my backend on the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your problem now.

As far as I know, Django is really dependant on the `User` model; it can be a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), but there has to be some sort of `User` model.

When you build your [own authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend), it still has to return `User` instances (or your custom `User` model instances).

For example:

File **auth_backends.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Loginteste

class MyAuthBackend:
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        if username is None or password is None:
            # nothing to do
            return None

        # get 'User' object
        try:
            usr = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        # get 'Loginteste' object
        try:
            loginteste = Loginteste.objects.get(username=username)
        except Loginteste.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        # authenticate user
        if not loginteste.check_password(password):
            # incorrect password
            return None

        return usr

    def get_user(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return None
```

File **settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'project_config.auth_backends.MyAuthBackend',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

---

The only relatively simple option you might have is to use the model `Loginteste` as your custom user model. Everything else involves overriding a lot of Djangos code to make it work.

Comment: Now I get it.
Every time you give a select, update, delete, will I make a different backend?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You will have this backend, and every `Loginteste` object has to have its corresponding `User` instance. You can even modify the auth backend to create a `User` instance if a certain `Loginteste` instance has no corresponding `User` yet.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know how to ask the question.
To do a select, update and delete I will have to be doing other backends and custons user models or is it just doing the views normally?

Comment: Ralf, I put the `"project.auth_backend.MyAuthBackend"` in the `"AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS"`, but even when I excused the application, it gives the following error.
: `ImportError: No module named 'HelpDesk.auth_backend'`